# MetaMask Automation with Selenium Driver Python - Unable to find element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, metamask

I am using the following Python code to find checkbox input element using By.XPATH on MetaMask extension page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

EXTENSION_PATH = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/11.7.2_0.crx" #enter the path to the metamask .crx file here

# Specify the path to chromedriver.exe
path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver.exe'
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
# opt.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver, options=opt)

time.sleep(1)
#switch tabs
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
time.sleep(8)

elem = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/input").click()
```

But the problem is that when I run the code, it loads extension page but doesn't click the check because as the code is not able to find it on the page. Following error raises:

```
**NoSuchElementException**: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.130)
```

I have also raised the issues on Github repository under the following link from where I got the code initially:
Issues 1: https://github.com/yuta-belmont/metamask_bf/issues/18
Issues 2: https://github.com/yuta-belmont/metamask_bf/issues/17

I have tried to use By.ID and By.CLASS method too in order to find the element but it raises the same error. Even I have tried several Selenium versions in order to confirm if there is issue with Selenium or not.

After spending several hours and not being able to fix this issue, I am here for guidance. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance. :)

[Screenshot of extension page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW72L.png)

Is there something I am doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Can you confirm if any other element are you able to locate? as its chrome-extensions page

Comment: @user3181500 I have tried to locate the other elements too but I am getting no element. I have tried to find it by name, class, ID, and xpath but unfortunately, I am getting the same error.

Comment: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-chrome-extensions-in-selenium#:~:text=Browser%20extensions%20are%20embedded%20add,automating%20user%20actions%20with%20Selenium. - can u check if it helps?